# HTML, CSS, jQuery - Height of divs in one column depending on the height of divs in another column

Tags: jquery, html, css, height, equals

I've got the following problem. Consider this example of html code:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id="leftColumn">
  <div id="div1"></div>
  <div id="div2"></div>
  <div id="div3"></div>
  <div id="div4"></div>
</div>
<div id="rightColumn">
  <div id="div1sidebar"></div>
  <div id="div2sidebar"></div>
  <div id="div3sidebar"></div>
  <div id="div4sidebar"></div>
</div>     
</body>
</html>
```

Now - height of divs in the left column vary, depending on the content inside them. I would like divs in the right column to be the same height as divs in the left column - so height of "div1sidebar" depends on "div1", "div2sidebar" depends on "div2", etc.

It there a way to achieve it with css only? Or with a jQuery for example? "Faux columns" method (http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) is not an option, because it's not about parents background, but the height of the divs itself.

EDIT: And one thing - height of the divs in left column change "on a fly", without reloading the site.

Answer (score 0):

You can `float` your elements left and right and use repeated `clear: both` to get them to align, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/eNRhQ/2/

This assures that the corresponding divs are always aligned, but as you can see by the borders, their heights are actually not the same. (You could only possible need this for styling purposes ...)

If you really want to align your divs programmatically, you can do it like this in jQuery:

```
var left = $('#left-element');
var right = $('#right-element');

var maxHeight = Math.max(left.height(), right.height());

left.height(maxHeight);
right.height(maxHeight);
```

But I would make sure that the page also looks ok without any Javascript

Comment: Hmm, thanks for your help, but in that jsfiddle example, html is bit different - I cannot change it this way; in my case those all left divs have to be in one left column, and all right divs have to be in right column. But anyway, I did it with:
`$("#div1sidebar").css({height: $("#div1").height() }); `

Although, there's still a problem with dynamic resizing. Why this code doesn't work? - 

`$("#div1").resize(function() {
   $("#div1sidebar").css({height: $("#div1").height() }); 
  });`

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those strange things that can't be done in CSS.

I use this plugin and it works great, http://www.cssnewbie.com/equalheights-jquery-plugin/

If you want this to stay up to date after resizing, you can do:

```
$(".columns").resize(function(){
  $(".columns").equalHeights();
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/resize/

Comment: Looks promising. Please tell me - is there a way to use it also with a dynamic resizing of one div ?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not working. Resizing divs doesn't change their height anyway.